# How can I test angular ui-router $stateChangeStart listeners?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, angular-ui-router

Here's a basic authentication scheme I'm using in angular. I'm trying to unit test this little chunk that listens for state changes and checks both if they need authentication and if the user is authenticated. If they're not authenticated it will prevent the state change.

```
angular.module('app').run(function ($rootScope, $state, auth) {

    // enable authenticated states
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState) {
        if (toState.authenticate && !auth.isAuthenticated()) {
            // prevent state change
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });

});
```

Here is what my unit test is looking like so far.

```
describe('events', function () {

// setup ------------------------------------------------------------------

    // init app module
    beforeEach(module('app'));

    // inject dependencies
    beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function (_$rootScope_, _$state_, _auth_) {
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
        $state     = _$state_;
        auth       = _auth_;
    }));

// tests ------------------------------------------------------------------

    // prevent state transition when unauthorized
    it('check if a user can view a given state', function () {
        $state.go('user');
        expect(auth.isAuthenticated).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(event.preventDefault()).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

});
```

I'm currently getting an error that it expected a spy but got a function for the first expectation and event is undefined in the second expectation. I've tried setting up a spy like so.

```
beforeEach(function () {
    spyOn(auth, 'isAuthenticated').andCallThrough();
});
```

With this included in the setup I get an error Expected spy isAuthenticated to have been called.  And I understand why event is undefined but am not sure how to fix it since it's an argument of an anonymous function. I would also like to test that toState.authenticate is being called but expect to run into the same issues.

Where do I go from here?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23655307/ui-router-interfers-with-httpbackend-unit-test-angular-js