# AngularJS Unit Test using HttpBackend.whenGet doesn't return expected result

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

According to the Angular docs for ngMock the $httpBackend when method should intercept $http service requests and serve the specified response. I assume that the mock $httpBackend methods would be synchronous to make testing easier.  But result.test ends up being undefined.

```
describe('Http requests', function () {
    var scope, $httpBackend, constituents;

    beforeEach(module('main'));

    beforeEach(inject(function (_$httpBackend_, _constituents_) {
        constituents = _constituents_;
        $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
        $httpBackend.expectGET("App/Main/login.html").respond(200);
    }));

    it('Should get the constituents', function () {
        $httpBackend.whenGET(webServicesPath + "api/constituents/all-constituents").respond(200, { "test": true });
        var result = constituents.getAllConstituents();
        $httpBackend.flush();
        expect(result.$$state.value.test).toEqual(true);
    });

});
```

I tried using $httpBackend.flush() but that has unintended consequences leading to this...

> Error: Unexpected request: GET App/Main/login.html

which means the ui.routing service got invoked somehow.  so I handled that by adding a `$httpBackend.expectGET...` in the `beforeEach`.

**Why do I have to even use the flush method?**  Seems overly complicated.  Why does it trigger ui.routing when that has nothing to do with my unit test?

For reference, this is the factory used

```
app.factory('constituents', ['$http', '$log', function ($http, $log) {
    function getAllConstituents() {
        return $http.get(webServicesPath + "api/constituents/all-constituents").then(
            function (response) {
                return response.data;
            },
            function (response) {
                $log.error("Load Constituents - " + response.status + " " + response.statusText);
                return;
            }
        );
    }
    return {
        getAllConstituents: getAllConstituents
    }
}]);
```

Comment: Where is this `webServicesPath` variable coming from? It seems to be `undefined` in both your spec and your factory.

Comment: it comes from somewhere else but I have verified that it is defined

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `results` variable is a promise not the result of the `$http` request. You would have to do something like this to access the result:

```
it('Should get the constituents', function () {
    var result;

    $httpBackend.whenGET('foo.json').respond(200, { "test": true });

    constituents
      .getAllConstituents()
      .then(function(response){
        result = response;
      });

    $httpBackend.flush();
    expect(result.test).toEqual(true);

});
```

> My question is why do I have to even use the flush method?

Because writing asynchronous unit tests can be hell. So we need to use the flush method to make our asynchronous tests synchronous which makes life much easier as we no longer need to create loads of fake promises and figure out where to put the `done()` callback that tells our test framework that the test is over etc. etc.

> Why does it trigger ui.routing when that has nothing to do with my
>   unit test?

You can read more about that in this SO question

[UI-router interfers with $httpbackend unit test, angular js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23655307/ui-router-interfers-with-httpbackend-unit-test-angular-js)

It can be a pain but I've found that using a helper library like [bardJS](https://github.com/wardbell/bardjs#fakeServices) is probably the quickest way to make `ui-router` problems go away and it also removes a lot of the boilerplate that you need to write for Angular unit tests.

Comment: Huge thanks for this.  I am wondering how much bard.asyncModule would reduce/change the current answer you produced?