# $stateChangeSuccess always being triggered in Unit Test

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

In my controller I've got two event listeners on the $scope, one for $stateChangeSuccess and one for a message event:

```
$scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function () {
  $scope.methodA();
});

$scope.$on('message', function () {
  $scope.methodB(); 
});
```

And in my unit test I only want to test that **methodB** has been called:

```
spyOn($scope, '$on').and.callThrough();
spyOn($scope, 'methodB');
$scope.$emit('message');
expect($scope.methodB).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

The problem is that $stateChangeSuccess is also being called, even though I don't emit the event myself. Should this be the case or have I misconfigured something in ui-router?

I can get around this by mocking the $stateChangeSuccess event, but I'd rather it not be called at all in my unit tests unless I emit the event myself.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this using the second answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23655307/ui-router-interfers-with-httpbackend-unit-test-angular-js/23670198#23670198).

Basically, you can disable ui-router in your unit tests by calling deferIntercept() on the $urlRouterProvider module.

```
beforeEach(module(function($urlRouterProvider) {
  $urlRouterProvider.deferIntercept();
}));
```

This and other ui-router related issues with karma/jasmine are explained [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/212#issuecomment-69974072).