# Jasmine test error on Jenkins Build Server with angular-mocks?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jenkins, httpbackend, angular-mock

I'm unit testing a angular directive with Angular and Jasmine.
Mocking the http backend works fine and all tests working fine locally. But on the build server i get:

> Error: Unexpected request: GET app/auth/views/login.html
>       No more request expected (line 1419)
>       $httpBackend@bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:1419:90
>       n@build/vendor.js:222:54
>       build/vendor.js:219:263
>       build/vendor.js:254:21
>       $eval@build/vendor.js:268:347
>       $digest@build/vendor.js:265:425

My test setup:

```
beforeEach(angular.mock.module("app"));

beforeEach(() => {
    inject(function ($injector, _$compile_, _$rootScope_) {
      // The injector unwraps the underscores (_) from around the parameter names when matching
      $compile = _$compile_;
      $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
      $httpBackend = $injector.get("$httpBackend");
    });

$httpBackend.whenGET("api/langs/gb.json").respond({ "COMMON.HOME": homeName });
$httpBackend.whenGET("api/langs/de.json").respond({});

$httpBackend.whenGET("app/home/views/dashboard.html").respond(200, "");
$httpBackend.whenGET("app/home/views/login.html").respond(200, "");
$httpBackend.whenGET(/^private\/auth\?.*/).respond({});

directiveElem = getCompiledElement();
  });
```

What is different on the build server. I can't explain this behavior.

Comment: Can you show the $httpBackend code that you are using to mock the `app/auth/views/login.html` file?

Comment: Could you also show the code for your directive?

Comment: Where is `http://localhost/app/auth/views/login.html `being referenced in an your provided samples. How are you including `login.html` in your app? Could you share the code that includes that file?

Comment: it is only used in the config

.config(function ($stateProvider) {

      $stateProvider
        .state("login", {
          url: "/login",
          views: {
            root: {
              templateUrl: "app/auth/views/login.html",
              controller: "AuthController"
            }
          },

Comment: I updated my answer. Take a look to see if that fixes your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UI-Router is attempting to load the `app/auth/views/login.html` file during your app startup.

If you run the Jasmine tests locally, you already have a web server setup at a url like `http://localhost`, so the request for `http://localhost/app/auth/views/login.html` will return the actual file. When you run this test on the build server, the build server is not configured to serve the `http://localhost/app/auth/views/login.html` url, so it returns a 404.

Here is an article describing how to work around that issue: [UI-router interfers with $httpbackend unit test, angular js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23655307/ui-router-interfers-with-httpbackend-unit-test-angular-js/23670198?noredirect=1#comment36365838_23670198)

Also, here's a github issue that goes into more detail about how to deal with this: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/212