# Jasmine Testing Angular 1.5 $state.go

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I have the following controller that has a function to redirect based on state.

```
(function() {

angular.module('CL.Authenticate')
    .controller('AuthenticateController', AuthenticateController);

AuthenticateController.$inject = ['$window', '$log', '$state', 'authenticationService', 'identity', 'UserService', 'MessagesService', 'ModalsService', '$location'];
function AuthenticateController($window, $log, $state, authenticationService, identity, userService, MessagesService, ModalsService, $location) {
    var vm = this;.......

function navigateToLoggedInState() {
        userService.getCurrentOrganisation().then(function(organisation) {
            if ($state.params.redirectUrl) {
                $location.path($state.params.redirectUrl);
            } else if (organisation.IsSupplier) {
                $state.go('dashboard.home.supplier');
            } else (organisation.IsBuyer) {
                $state.go('dashboard.home.buyer');
            }
        });
    }....
```

The state machine is declared in a config file:

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular.module('CL.Dashboard').config(['$stateProvider', 'DashboardConstants', dashboardConfig])
    .run(['$rootScope', '$state', 'UserService', function($rootScope, $state, userService){
        $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState){
            if (toState.name === 'dashboard.home'){
                event.preventDefault();
                userService.getCurrentOrganisation().then(function(organisation){
                    if (organisation.IsSupplier){
                        $state.go('dashboard.home.supplier');
                    } else (organisation.IsBuyer) {
                        $state.go('dashboard.home.buyer');
                    } 
                });
            }
        });
    }]);
function dashboardConfig ($stateProvider, DashboardConstants) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('dashboard.home', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: 'dashboard/home.html',
            controller: 'DashboardController',
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            resolve: {
                pasStatus: ['DashboardService', function(DashboardService){
                    return DashboardService.getPasStatus();
                }]
            }
        })
        .state('dashboard.home.buyer', {
            url: 'buyer',
            templateUrl: 'dashboard/buyer/buyer.html',
            controller: 'DashboardBuyerController',
            controllerAs: 'vm'
        }).....
```

In my spec.js file I have:

```
describe('Authenticate Controller', function () {

beforeEach(module('CL.Authenticate'));
beforeEach(module('CL.Users'));
beforeEach(module('CL.Dashboard'));

describe('authenticate controller', function () {

    var $log, $scope, $state, authenticationService, controller, userService, ModalsService, $stateProvider;;

    beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, _$state_, $controller, _$log_, $injector, $q, _identity_, _UserService_) {
        $log = _$log_;
        $scope = $rootScope.$new();
        $state = _$state_;
        userService = _UserService_;


        authenticationService = $injector.get('authenticationService');
        controller = $controller('AuthenticateController', {$scope: $scope, $log: $log, identity: _identity_, userService: userService, ModalsService: ModalsService});

        spyOn(authenticationService, "authenticate").and.callFake(function (emailAddress, password) {
.......
expect(authenticationService.authenticate).toHaveBeenCalledWith('test@test.com', 'password123', true, { 401: false });
```

On the expect statement As part of the authenticate method the navigateToLoggedInState is called, when the line **$state.go('dashboard.home.supplier');** gets hit I get the following error:

**Could not resolve 'dashboard.home.supplier' from state ''
    at Object.transitionTo (angular-ui-router.js:3179)**

What have I missed in my setup for my state? this doesn't seem to be a duplicate of the answer identified by @tanmay because I'm not calling $state directly in my test. I did however try by creating a new file and following the example given, but I still received the same error.

Comment: Just don't test with `ui-router` module loaded and real `$state`. Mock it.

Comment: @estus the trouble is because I'm not calling state directly in my test, but from the actual authenticate method, since I'm unit testing here, I cannot easily just mock $state without mocking the whole authentication layer.

Comment: Well, you need to mock auth layer here, too, because you unit-test a controller, aren't you?

Comment: @bilpor can you make a plunker/fiddle for unit-test of this? Would be easier to figure out a solution..

Comment: @tanmay I'll see what I can do. The network here is heavily restricted.

Comment: @bilpor here's an example of such fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/fdietz/2Ny8x/

Comment: @tanmay  I've tried to place the code in fiddle, but because I'm trying to fix someone else's tests, against code already written, it's spiralling out into almost having to place tons of files into fiddler to make it work even trying to remove services etc that I don't need for this example

Answer (score 0):

I still think the solution lies in [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23670198/4315380) only. Let me put down a list of all the things you would need to do.

- Take the `stateMock` module from [this gist](https://gist.github.com/wilsonwc/8358542)
- Make sure it is available through inclusion of `stateMock` module's JS file in your karma unit-test files
- Module should be available in spec through `beforeEach(module('stateMock'));`
- Inject it in your spec

  ```
  beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $state, $controller, _$log_, 
  $injector, $q, _identity_, _UserService_) {
    $log = _$log_;
    $scope = $rootScope.$new();
    state = $state;
    userService = _UserService_;
    ...
  ```
- Now in your spec, **before you call the controller function**, add `expectTransitionTo` like this:

  ```
  state.expectTransitionTo('dashboard.home.supplier');
  ```

The last point is little tricky since we generally tend to put anything related to `expect` after the actual function call :)

Hope it works!

Comment: I've done all of the above. at the point I call the state.expectTransitionTo I receive the following error:  **TypeError: state.expectTransitionTo is not a function**

Comment: @bilpor looks like there is some issue in either injecting it or including it. Check for those errors. If using IDE, does your ctrl+click on the use of `expectTransitionTo` leads to its implementation? I am using the same `stateMock` in my project and it works like a charm

Comment: If I place a breakpoint on the expectTransitionTo call and look at $state this isn't shown.  It doesn't complain about the declaration of it on the beforeEach statement, I have declared it in my karma file

Comment: @bilpor I can't do much about it then. Get it sanity checked with any peer maybe?

Comment: thanks @tanmay for trying to help. There is no one else, hence coming here. I'll keep trying things. One thought  though in my karma file, does it matter where in my list of included files it should go i.e. first or at the bottom

Comment: @bilpor before you list any of your spec files i.e. as above as possible