# AngularJS + Karma-Jasmine: Unexpected Request + UI Router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I am trying to Unit Test an AngularJS HTTP Service with the help of Karma-Jasmine.
But I am facing the following Error from Karma:

```
Error: Unexpected request: GET app/license/license.html
```

I Googled and found out that it has something to do with **ui-router**.
The following StackOverflow Link: ([UI-router interfers with $httpbackend unit test, angular js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23655307/ui-router-interfers-with-httpbackend-unit-test-angular-js/23670198#23670198)) suggests some Answers, but none of them works for me and the Error remains the same.

I am posting my code below for reference:

**licensedata.service.js**

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    angular
        .module("app")
        .factory("licenseDataService", licenseDataService)

    licenseDataService.$inject = ["$http"];

    function licenseDataService($http) {

        return {
            getLicenseSpecs: getLicenseSpecs
        };

        function getLicenseSpecs() {
            return $http.get("http://localhost:8080/?command=print-spec")
                .then(success)
                .catch(fail);

            function success(response) {
                return response.data;
            }

            function fail(e) {
                return e.data;
            }
        }
    }
})();
```

**licensedata.service.spec.js**

```
describe("LICENSE DATA SERVICE", function () {

    var licenseDataService;
    var httpBK;

    beforeEach(angular.mock.module("app"));

    beforeEach(angular.mock.module(function ($urlRouterProvider) {
        $urlRouterProvider.deferIntercept();
    }));

    beforeEach(inject(function (_licenseDataService_, $httpBackend) {
        licenseDataService = _licenseDataService_;
        httpBK = $httpBackend;
    }));

    it("Test License Key", function () {
        var returnData = {};

        httpBK.expectGET("http://localhost:8080/?command=print-spec").respond(returnData);

        var returnedPromise = licenseDataService.getLicenseSpecs();

        var result;
        returnedPromise.then(function (response) {
            result = response.data;
        });

        httpBK.flush();
    });
});
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you remove 2nd beforeEach everything should work. Not sure what you are trying to achieve with these lines and how ui-router is related to this test.

Comment: My goal is to Unit Test the LicenseData Service. The function getLicenseSpecs() returns a XML, which I want to test. And even I am not sure what ui-router has to do with it. But the error that I am getting, when I Google the error, all I can find is that it has something to do with ui-router. I removed the 2nd beforeEach() and still its giving me the same error.

Comment: man there is no 'license.html' mentioned here. There is no 'app/license' either, and code you gave here just works https://plnkr.co/edit/kEuvAW6eXImvffdsvxHF?p=preview

Comment: "app/license/license.html" is a templateUrl in the app.module.js file. And if you can read my above comment properly, I am talking about directly testing a $http Service. Your plnkr code is about testing a Controller and it does not have my code.