# Passing $stateParams to $controller is empty object when testing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

I'm trying to test a function in my controller that needs $stateParams to be mocked.  I'm trying to inject it into the $controller function, but it seems to be an empty object.

Here's how I'm injecting it:

```
stateParams = { configuratorName: "Awesome" };

var configuratorCtrl = $controller('ConfiguratorController', { $scope: $scope, $stateParmas: stateParams});
```

I looked at [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21317377/injected-stateparams-and-state-into-jasmine-angular-js-test-getting-undefined), and as far as I can tell I seem to be doing the same thing, more or less, but it just isn't working for me.  I do have more more dependencies listed in my controller than I do in the $controller function call, if that matters.

Any thoughts?

Comment: $stateParams is misspelled. You have "$stateParmas", it should be "$stateParams"

Comment: Hokey Smokes.  Thanks.  An hour on a typo.

Comment: Its happened to me plenty of times, lol. I posted comment as answer so you can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a misspelling of $stateParams.

You have **$stateParmas** and it should be **$stateParams**.