# Unit Testing AngularJS Controller with $route injection

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to write a test for an Angular controller which takes $route as an injectable. Inside the controller it references this object in various places e.g.`$route.current.params`

I'm trying to work out the best way to write this test. I don't believe using the $location service to set the url will work as I need to unit test functionality inside the controller so I need the $controller service to create an instance of the controller under test.

So far all I can think of is to manually mock the $route service but this seems like a lot of work that ought to have been done before. The trouble is I can't seem to find any examples. The closest I can find is '[Injected $stateParams and $state into jasmine angular js test getting undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21317377/injected-stateparams-and-state-into-jasmine-angular-js-test-getting-undefined?rq=1)' but this isn't exactly my situation.

I can inject $route of course but it won't have any of the specific properties of the route set. What's the generally accepted way to approach this?

Answer (score 0):

Unless it is ngRoute module that is tested (which is unlikely), its services should be mocked in unit tests to reduce the amount of moving parts.

`$routeParams` service can be recommended for its conciseness as direct replacement for `$route.current.params`, with few exceptions mentioned in [the manual](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams):

> Note that the $routeParams are only updated after a route change
>   completes successfully. This means that you cannot rely on
>   $routeParams being correct in route resolve functions. Instead you can
>   use $route.current.params to access the new route's parameters.